# Problems with pie chart

Tags: php

I just made a pie chart with PHP(ajax) and Jquery... Now I am having two small problems I hope you can fix. The first one is... On my webpage it is showing part of the code I am using. When I remove the code it's not working anymore.

[image]
The part that is showing on the screen is ("gestemd" => "$a", "stemmen" => "$d") Like:

[image]

I don't understand why the { tag is showing on screen and ( in the code.

My second problem which is also not that big of a problem is.... My picture background is red I want to change that in white. How do I do that? I am using an image in my database that changes when clicking on A B C or D. Color part of the slices:

[image]

You can see it work: http://72321.ict-lab.nl/test/Opdracht3/opdracht3.php

Page code:

```
<?
require_once ("../../connection.php");
$opdracht = "SELECT * FROM MEOJ1_Opdracht3";
$result = mysql_query($opdracht);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $votes[] = array(
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "partij" => $row['partij'],
        "stemmen" => $row['stemmen']
    );
}
include ("stemmen.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Opdracht 3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<button name="p1" id="p1">Partij A</button><br>
<button name="p2" id="p2">Partij B</button><br>
<button name="p3" id="p3">Partij C</button><br>
<button name="p4" id="p4">Partij D</button>

<p id="text">Gestemd op: <span id="gestemd"></span></p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="rood"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <? echo $votes[0]['partij'] ?>: <span id="stemmen1"><? echo $votes[0]['stemmen'] ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="geel"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <? echo $votes[1]['partij'] ?>: <span id="stemmen2"><? echo $votes[1]['stemmen'] ?></span>
        </td>
    <tr>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <div class="blauw"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <? echo $votes[2]['partij'] ?>: <span id="stemmen3"><? echo $votes[2]['stemmen'] ?></span>
        </td>
    <tr>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <div class="groen"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <? echo $votes[3]['partij'] ?>: <span id="stemmen4"><? echo $votes[3]['stemmen'] ?></span>
        </td>
</table>


<div id="afbeelding">
    <img src='http://72321.ict-lab.nl/database/stemmen.png' alt="Stem diagram" title="Stem diagram" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#p1" ).click(function() {
        vote(1);
    });
    $( "#p2" ).click(function() {
        vote(2);
    });
    $( "#p3" ).click(function() {
        vote(3);
    });
    $( "#p4" ).click(function() {
        vote(4);
    });

    function vote(partij) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "stemmen.php?partij="+partij,
            dataType: "text json",
            success: function(data) {
                var gestemd = data.gestemd;
                var stemmen = data.stemmen;
                document.getElementById('gestemd').innerHTML=gestemd;
                document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'inherit';
                document.getElementById('stemmen'+gestemd).innerHTML=stemmen;
                document.getElementById('afbeelding').innerHTML="<img src='http://72321.ict-lab.nl/database/stemmen.png' />";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

vote(stemmen.php) code:

```
<?php

require_once("../../connection.php");

$a = $_GET['partij'];
$b = mysql_query("SELECT stemmen FROM MEOJ1_Opdracht3 WHERE id = ".$a);
$c = mysql_fetch_array($b);
$d = $c['stemmen'];
$d = $d + 1;
$b = mysql_query("UPDATE MEOJ1_Opdracht3 SET stemmen = ".$d." WHERE id = ".$a);
$e = array("gestemd" => "$a", "stemmen" => "$d");
print_r(json_encode($e));
$f = "SELECT stemmen FROM meoj1_opdracht3";
$g = mysql_query($f);
while ($h = mysql_fetch_array($g))
{
    $i[] = array("stemmen" => $h['stemmen']);
}

$j = $i[0]['stemmen'];
$k = $i[1]['stemmen'];
$l = $i[2]['stemmen'];
$m = $i[3]['stemmen'];
$n = $j + $k + $l + $m;
$o = 360 / $n;
$p = $j * $o;
$q = $k * $o;
$r = $l * $o;
$s = $m * $o;
$t = imagecreate(300, 300);
$u = imagecolorallocate($t, 198, 7, 18);
$v = imagecolorallocate($t, 200, 198, 41);
$w = imagecolorallocate($t, 6, 25, 196);
$x = imagecolorallocate($t, 30, 198, 33);
imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, 0, $p, $u, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, $p, ($p + $q), $v, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, ($p + $q), ($p + $q + $r), $w, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, ($p + $q + $r), ($p + $q + $r + $s), $x, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagepng($t, "../../database/stemmen.png");

?>
```

database:
[image]

Comment: What is the code for that page?

Comment: put the code u have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a `print_r(json_encode($e));` in `stemmen.php`. This will output what you see in the screen. 
   The problem is that `stemmen.php` seems to be meant for AJAX results, as it returns a JSON string. What you need to do, is remove the `include ("stemmen.php");` since you are already calling this code with AJAX. If you remove it, you should see it go away.
2. In `stemmen.php`, you are setting your background color to red, but you are not defining a color for that empty section. if you want to change the background to white but still see red for that empty section, you need to do the following:

   change this:

   ```
   $t = imagecreate(300, 300);
   $u = imagecolorallocate($t, 198, 7, 18);
   $v = imagecolorallocate($t, 200, 198, 41);
   $w = imagecolorallocate($t, 6, 25, 196);
   $x = imagecolorallocate($t, 30, 198, 33);
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, 0, $p, $u, IMG_ARC_PIE);
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, $p, ($p + $q), $v, IMG_ARC_PIE);
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, ($p + $q), ($p + $q + $r), $w, IMG_ARC_PIE);
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, ($p + $q + $r), ($p + $q + $r + $s), $x, IMG_ARC_PIE);
   imagepng($t, "../../database/stemmen.png");
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   $t = imagecreate(300, 300);
   $u = imagecolorallocate($t, 255, 255, 255); // BACKGROUND WHiTE
   $red = imagecolorallocate($t, 198, 7, 18); //CREATES THE RED FOR THE SECTION
   $v = imagecolorallocate($t, 200, 198, 41);
   $w = imagecolorallocate($t, 6, 25, 196);
   $x = imagecolorallocate($t, 30, 198, 33);
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, 0, $p, $red, IMG_ARC_PIE); //creates RED SECTION
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, $p, ($p + $q), $v, IMG_ARC_PIE);
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, ($p + $q), ($p + $q + $r), $w, IMG_ARC_PIE);
   imagefilledarc($t, 125, 125, 200, 200, ($p + $q + $r), ($p + $q + $r + $s), $x, IMG_ARC_PIE);
   imagepng($t, "../../database/stemmen.png");
   ```
3. The third problem you are having, I believe has to do with how you are appending your new image in JS. When you append a new image, you have to tell the browser it changed. Since the image name is the same, you have to create some type of string that changes the image name in order for the browser to know it has changed. One way to do this is by coming up with a time string and placing it at the of the image. Try this:

   change this:

   ```
   document.getElementById('afbeelding').innerHTML = "<img src='http://72321.ict-lab.nl/database/stemmen.png' />";
   ```

   to this:

   ```
    var time = (new Date).getTime();
    document.getElementById('afbeelding').innerHTML = "<img src='http://72321.ict-lab.nl/database/stemmen.png?"+time+"' />";
   ```

To return the name:

```
$b = mysql_query("SELECT partij, stemmen FROM MEOJ1_Opdracht3 WHERE id = ".$a);
$c = mysql_fetch_array($b);
$d = $c['stemmen'];
 $name = $c['partij'];
....
$e = array("gestemd" => "$a", "stemmen" => "$d", "name"=> $name);
...
```